# In AWS Cognito - how to allow only specific email addresses from signing up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito in javascript with the amazon-cognito-identity-js package and it has been great.

**I am wondering, how is it possible to only allow users with certain email address endings to go through the signup flow?**

For example, only people who enter email address ending with ....@companyABC.com will be allowed to sign up and get the confirmation code sent to that email address. This will prevent people outside the company from accessing the application. The app does not have any top secret information, but we want only users within our company to access it.

I look to User Pool Settings and online but haven't been able to find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the solution? I can't yet.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Pre Sign Up Lambda trigger to check the user's email and then accept or deny the registration request, [more info.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html)

Comment: In pre-signup you can only mark the user as auto-confirmed or not
but, if user comes from external provider, like google or facebook, it will pass through, apparently auto-confirm parameter is not affecting those users.

Comment: The documentation is silent on how to _deny_ sign up.  Raising an exception results in a LambdaUserException which is indistinguishable from unanticipated exceptions.

Comment: Documentation has probably been updated since the above, but it does now state how to deny signup: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-registration-example-3

Answer (score 3):

I was able to achieve that with pre-signup lambda trigger, couldn't find a way to restrict access using configuration only.

This is my lambda function code

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log ("Trigger function =", event.triggerSource);

    // Send post authentication data to Cloudwatch logs
    if (event.request.userAttributes.email.endsWith('@mydomain.com')) {
            console.log ("Authentication successful: ", event.request);
            callback(null, event);
    } else {
        console.log ("Authentication failed: ", event.request);
        callback("can't connect to admin", event)
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Cognito has various 'triggers' that are invoked with Lambda to allow custom processing like this. You could try Chris' login in the pre sign up trigger, perhaps?

Comment: Nope doesn't work. None of the Cognito triggers provide a way to deny a signup request which is bizarre. Pre Signup allows you to only update three built in flags in the event.response and that's about it,

Answer (score -6):

if using angular 2

```
<input
        type="text" class="form-control" id="loginEmail"
        required
        pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*(@companyABC.com)$"
        [(ngModel)]="email" name="loginEmail"
        #loginEmail="ngModel">
```

https://regex101.com/r/Y6P47P/3

Comment: that code is one the browser and is alterable by somebody. I need a serverside i.e AWS solution.

Comment: you cane do the regex check on server side too. you should do it in both.